# Accessing controller variables from a view

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have two controllers named A & B, and a view.  Assume view's context is controller B.  How do I access variables in controller A from a function within the view?

Comment: ptmoy2 ... Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In controller B, you should define that controller B needs controller A:

```
needs: ['controllerA']
```

Then in view B, you can access these variables using:

```
this.get('controller.controllers.controllerA.xxx')
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

If you are trying to access these variables from a template, then in template B you can use:

```
{{controllers.controllerA.xxx}}
```

Or even better, create an alias in controller B:

```
needs: ['controllerA'],
xxx: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.controllerA.xxx'),
```

then in your template B you can use:

```
{{xxx}}
```